# How to keep view when changing tab in TabbedViewNavigatorApplication

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder

I'm working on a flex 4.6 mobile project
and I found TabbedViewNavigatorApplication will destory the old view and create a new view every time change a tab.

For example, user entered some text at a textInput in View1, then user change to View2 tab and change back to View1 tab. at this time, the entered text is gone.

My question is
How to keep these view instance when changing tabs(just like iphone tabbar did)?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `destructionPolicy="never"`property in View component?